# How to properly unpack a nested dictionary in a django HTML template?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

So I was able to figure out how to unpack a dictionary keys and values on to a HTML template, but I am a bit confused as to how to unpack if if a dictionary value is a QuerySet. For example I passing in all the timeslots of the given user into the dictonary. How can I unpack the attributes of the TimeSlot QuerySet for each timeslot such as the start time and end time?

This is my HTML Template:

```
<table>
    {% for key, value in user_info.items %}
        {% for key2,value2 in value.items %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{key2}}</td>
            <td>{{value2}}<td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        <br>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

My function in views.py

```
def check_food_availibility(request):
    food = FoodAvail.objects.all()
    timeslots = TimeSlot.objects.all()
    users_dict = {}
    for i in range(len(user_info)):
        user = {
            "author": None,
            "food_available": None,
            "description": None,
            "timeslot": None
        }
        user["author"] = user_info[i].author.username
        user["food_available"] = user_info[i].food_available
        user["description"] = user_info[i].description
        if TimeSlot.objects.filter(time_slot_owner=user_info[i].author):
            user["timeslot"] = TimeSlot.objects.filter(time_slot_owner=user_info[i].author)
        users_dict[user_info[i].author.username] = user

    return render(request, "food_avail/view_food_avail.html", {"user_info": users_dict})
```

This is how it shows up currently:
[image]

Comment: Where does `user_info` come from in your view? Can you add your models? You shouldn't need to create a dictionary and dynamically iterate over it, you know it's keys so you can use them explicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<table>
    {% for key, value in user_info.items %}
        {% for key2,value2 in value.items %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{key2}}</td>
          {% if key2 == 'timeslot' %}
           <td>
         {% for i in value2 %}

            i.start_time <-> i.end_time // just an example put your field here

         {% endfor %}
          
           </td>
          {% else %}
            <td>{{value2}}<td>
   
          {% endif %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        <br>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
```